# Is there a way I can create a custom toolbar button for Firefox 26 that is written in javascript and has access to the currently loaded page?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, document

I need to have a button that I can add to a toolbar that is written in javascript and has access to the document object of a webpage. I tried to use Custom Buttons, but calling `document.documentElement.innerHTML` returned something other than the current webpage. Is there some other method of doing this or another extension that supports this?

I used to be able to accomplish this by making a bookmark with the url `javascript:[some code]` but firefox has since removed that feature.

Link to Custom Buttons: https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried with the "Custom Buttons" add-on you mentioned:

```
document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.document.getElementById("foo")
```

works in Firefox 29.